# how to find Similar values(number) in array and the merge similars?

Tags: javascript, array-merge

I have sample array and I want to find duplicates(similar) numbers in array and then merge.

```
var arr = [{
'title': 'abc',
'number': 1
},{
'title': 'def',
'number': 1
},{
'title': 'ghi',
'number': 2
}];
```

and then merged must be like

```
var arr = [{
'title': ['abc', 'def'],
'number': 1
},{
'title': 'ghi',
'number': 2
}];
```

I mean duplicate's title must be merged into one and duplicate must be deleted.

Comment: Having two different types for a particular field is not highly recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to reduce the data to an object using the unique keys to capture the data that is common:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  var key = c.number;

  // if the object doesn't exist, create a new one
  // and set it's value as a pre-filled object
  p[key] = p[key] || { title: [], number: key };

  // then add the title to the title array
  p[key].title.push(c.title);
  return p;
}, {});
```

And then recreate the array of objects using `map` on the object keys:

```
var data = Object.keys(obj).map(function (el) {
  return { title: obj[el].title, number: el };
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mobvLrv9/)

This will give you an array for title regardless of how many elements are in there and is the right way to go (see @thefourtheye's comment).

If, however, you want to only have an array if there are two or more elements in the title array, you can change the code slightly:

```
var data = Object.keys(obj).map(function (el) {
  var title = obj[el].title;
  return {
    title: title.length === 1 ? title[0] : title,
    number: el
  };
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5z0k2cx0/1/)

Comment: where is console field in jsfiddle? :D I doesn't find

Comment: jsfiddle uses the browser console - F12 to open.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach with a temporary object which holds the reference to the array and the result array itself.

Duplicate `title` with the same `number` is only inserted once (like `{ 'title': 'xxx', 'number': 42 }`).

```js
var arr = [{ 'title': 'xxx', 'number': 42 }, { 'title': 'xxx', 'number': 42 }, { 'title': 'abc', 'number': 1 }, { 'title': 'def', 'number': 1 }, { 'title': 'ghi', 'number': 2 }],
    result = arr.reduce(function (r, b) {
        if (b.number in r.o) {
            if (!(b.title in r.o[b.number])) {
                r.a[r.o[b.number].index].title.push(b.title);
                r.o[b.number][b.title] = true;
            }
            return r;
        }
        r.o[b.number] = { index: r.a.push({ title: [b.title], number: b.number }) - 1 };
        r.o[b.number][b.title] = true;
        return r;
    }, { o: {}, a: [] }).a;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution loops across the elements, and filters out the second and succeeding elements with the same number, but before doing so adds their title to the first occurrence. In other words, it almost exactly follows your proposed "algorithm", to

> I mean duplicate's title must be merged into one and duplicate must be deleted.

```
array.filter(function(elt, idx) {
  var number = elt.number;
  var title  = elt.title;

  // Check if an element has a number that matches the current one.
  function sameNumber(elt) { return number === elt.number; }

  // Find the index of the first array element with the same number.
  var first = findIndex(array, sameNumber);

  // If this is the first, just pass it through the filter.
  if (idx === first) return true;

  // Otherwise, concatenate our title with the title of the first occurrence.
  array[first].title = [].concat(array[first].title, title);
}
```

where `findIndex` is (could also use `Array#findIndex` if available):

```
function findIndex(array, condition) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (condition(array[i])) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

If you want `title` to always be an array, even if that number occurs only once, then change the relevant lines as follows:

```
  // If this is the first, just pass it through the filter.
  if (idx === first) { elt.title = [elt.title]; return true; }

  // Otherwise, concatenate our title with the title of the first occurrence.
  array[first].title.push(title);
```

This avoids having to create some other object-like representation of the data, and then converting back into the array format.

Comment: can you write this code by default javascript? I don't understand anything :/

Comment: and where is result? I open console but nothing to show :( where can I see result?

Comment: I will put up a fiddle when I get a chance.